# How to dynamically call a form in C++ Builder XE3?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe3

I'm building an application in which Im populating menus using DB. I can create menu items but im having trouble linking "On Click" event to particular forms. I have stored names of the forms classes in my DB and trying to use RTTI to bind them at runtime. Following is the snippet of my code that Im trying to run.

```
__fastcall TfrmMainMDI::TfrmMainMDI(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    // Register 2 form classes
    RegisterClass(__classid(TfrmSecurity));
    RegisterClass(__classid(TfrmPassword)); 
}
```

Now when I try to run following code to call the form it gives "Access violation" error.

```
    TForm *frm = (TForm*)TFormClass(FindClass(formName));
    UnicodeString str = frm->Name;
    frm->Show();
```

Comment: Try this: `TForm *frm = 0; Application->CreateForm( TFormClass(FindClass(formName)), &frm);` and then if `frm` is not null any more, `frm->Show()`

Comment: @MattMcNabb you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: I haven't actually used RegisterClass/FindClass before, I got the idea from [this page](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20565).  Also I'm not sure exactly what happens if the form creation fails, and not sure if it would still work to go `Application->CreateForm( FindClass(formName) ), &frm );` which is simpler if it does work! Hopefully an expert can jump in.

Comment: I have been trying to use this RegisterClass method for the last 3 hours without any success. I already checked that link as well but the information is a bit too confusing for me. I tried to "convert" the delphi code line by line to C++ but it didnt work.
Your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: C++ does not support creating objects from class references. That is a feature of Delphi, which `CreateForm()` (and most of the RTL/VCL is general) is written in. `CreateForm()` will raise an exception if creation fails, as well `FindClass()` if it cannot find the registered class. `CreateForm()` also has a side effect that the `Application` is always assigned as the `Owner` of the new Form. If you do not want that, you will have to roll your own `CreateForm()` code, or use `TComponent::RemoveComponent()` and `TComponent::InsertComponent()` to change the Form's `Owner` after construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
TForm *frm = 0;
Application->CreateForm( TFormClass(FindClass(formName)), &frm );
```

Then if `frm` is not null,

```
frm->Show();
```

Comment: You do not need the type-cast to `TFormClass`.  In C++, `FindClass()` returns a `TMetaClass*`, which is the same input that `CreateForm()` expects, so no cast is needed. `CreateForm()` will never return a `NULL` pointer, it will raise an exception if a failure occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
TForm *frm = new TForm(this);

if( frm != NULL )
{
   frm->ShowModal();

   //or

   frm->Show();
}
```